# Calling a PHP function only gives one row from the query result

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a PHP file to store all the functions I need in my project.
One of them is the following:

```
function recuperar_opcion_plato_linea ($plato_id) {

/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'xxxx';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = 'xxxxxxx';

try {
 $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=xxx", $username, $password);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/


    /*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_opciones_linea_comanda WHERE id_linea = '".$plato_id."'";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
        {
        return $row['id_opcion'];
        }

    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }


}
```

From another file I am calling this function but it only gives the first row of the query result, and there are at least 3 rows.

And this is the PHP piece of code to call the function recuperar_opcion_plato_linea:

```
<?php do { ?>
      <p><?php echo $row_Recordset1['cantidad_pedido']." "; ?>
      <?php echo recuperar_nombre_plato($row_Recordset1['plato_pedido'])." "."$ ".$row_Recordset1['precio_linea']." ".$moneda?></p>
      <p><?php 
      $opcion_selecionada = recuperar_opcion_plato_linea ($row_Recordset1['id_random']);
      echo recuperar_nombre_opcion($opcion_selecionada) ?></p>
        <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
```

How can I get all rows from the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say `return $row['id_opcion'];` that ends your foreach loop immediately and tells the function to return.  Instead, you should simply `return $dbh->query($sql)`

Also, if all you need from your query is one column `id_opcion` you should use `SELECT id_opcion` instead of `SELECT *`

For the sake of example, let's say you still wanted to use a loop, you'd do it like this:

```
// create a blank results array
$results = array();

foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
    // add the row to the array
    $results[] = $row['id_opcion'];
}

// return the finished results array
return $results;
```

Comment: Thank you Ben, but I don't need an array. I have changed, as you propose, the query as SELECT id_opcion, and then I have simply change the return line as: echo $row['id_opcion']. Now I am getting the needed rows...thank you again

Comment: Ben, would you mind if I change my vote and accept the answer from Alex?

Comment: He posted the exact same answer I gave you 20 minutes after I did, but do whatever you feel is right.  The array you said you didn't need (that he provided in his example) is almost a direct copy paste of what I provided.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_opciones_linea_comanda WHERE id_linea = '".$plato_id."'";

foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
{
    return $row['id_opcion'];
}
```

With

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_opciones_linea_comanda WHERE id_linea = '".$plato_id."'";
$return = array();    
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
{
    $return[] = $row['id_opcion'];
}
return $return;
```

And

```
echo recuperar_nombre_opcion($opcion_selecionada)
```

With

```
foreach ($opcion_selecionadas AS $opcion_selecionada) {echo '<br />' . recuperar_nombre_opcion($opcion_selecionada);}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$return = array();
while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1))  == true)
{
   array_push($return, $row_Recordset1);
   // or $return[] = $row_Recordset1;
}

return $return;
```